# Pipe is not working

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

My pipe file is looking like this:

**pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({   name: 'unique',   pure: false 
}) export class UniquePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
        // Remove the duplicate elements
        let uniqueArray = value.filter(function (el, index, array) { 
          return array.indexOf (el) == index;
        });

        return uniqueArray;

       }

}
```

**component ts**

```
import { UniquePipe } from './../../../services/unique.pipe';
```

**component html**

```
   <li *ngFor="let dealOPtion of
deal['products'][dealindex]['options'];let dealOpt = index |
unique">
                        {{ dealOpt }}
                        {{dealOPtion['option_name'] |json}}
     </li>
```

Comment: share you coe here : https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: @PranayRana examples on platforms like StackBlitz should only be *supporting* the question - a [mcve] should be in the question itself.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - if you read comment on my answer , his orginal issue is resolved and now he is having another issue that pipe is not working , previously he is having compiler error which already resolved by my answer

Comment: @PranayRana then they should either edit this question or open a new one **with a [mcve] in**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it should be like this

```
  <li *ngFor="let dealOPtion of
(deal['products'][dealindex]['options']  |
unique) ;let dealOpt = index">
```

put piple after collection

---

as per comment you forgot to declare you pipe at module level so do as below

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
  ],
  declarations: [UniquePipe ],
  providers: [],
  exports: [UniquePipe ]//this is needed if you want to export pipe
})
export class PipesModule { }
```

Comment: i am getting error    Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'unique' could not be found ("al of products['bundled_items'];let dealindex = index">
                    <li *ngFor="let dealOPt[ERROR ->]ion of (deal['products'][dealindex]['options']  |
                    unique) ;let dealOpt = index">"):

Comment: @lintojohny then presumably you *haven't* actually declared the pipe in the module. Maybe read [the pipe docs](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#custom-pipes)?

Comment: @lintojohny - declare it at module level

Comment: yeah, the error is gone. but I added the pipe to eliminate repeating elements from the loop. it's not working

Comment: @lintojohny - i dont know your input data i.e. pipe input or collection strucute you have to share code some where so can help further, i suggest try to debug and check structure and code according to it

Comment: import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({   name: 'unique',   pure: false 
}) export class UniquePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
        // Remove the duplicate elements
        let uniqueArray = value.filter(function (el, index, array) { 
          return array.indexOf (el) == index;
        });

        return uniqueArray;

       }

}after search i got this pipe code to eliminate repeated items from the array

Comment: @lintojohny - it diffcult please share code on stackbiz.com